# Disable "Server unavailable or unreachable" popup notification in jupyterlab

Tags: jupyter-lab

I want to read a document in jupyterlab. The server is down, so every few seconds a popup appears:

> Server unavailable or unreachable
>
> Your server at /asdf is not running. Would you like to restart it?
>
> [Restart] --- [Dismiss]

I don't care about that. I simply want to read the document as it is, in peace, without being bothered by this popup. How do I "dismiss" it permanently?